# Strange bug in R package check: cleanEx() or dev.off()

Tags: r, bioinformatics, r-package, bioconductor

I'm not sure what's going on here...I'm trying to develop an R package for Bioconductor, and there's a strange bug showing up when examples are run in the package check.

```
Running examples in ‘MMAPPR2-Ex.R’ failed
The error most likely occurred in:
> ### Name: prePeak
> ### Title: Identify chromosomes containing peaks
> ### Aliases: prePeak
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> postPrePeakMD <- prePeak(postLoessMD)
> 
> 
> 
> ### * <FOOTER>
> ###
> cleanEx()
> options(digits = 7L)
> base::cat("Time elapsed: ", proc.time() - base::get("ptime", pos = 'CheckExEnv'),"\n")
Time elapsed:  423.952 27.296 464.105 0.004 0.14 
> grDevices::dev.off()
Error in grDevices::dev.off() : 
  cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
```

As you can see, the bug is not in my code, but rather in this "FOOTER" section automatically generated afterwards. I don't know how my package could have messed up graphics devices, since it only deals them with one spot, and I commented out where that part gets run in the examples. I'm not sure what to do.

Here's the Travis build with the problem in question: https://travis-ci.org/kjohnsen/MMAPPR2/builds/436922565

Comment: Maybe more suitable for https://support.bioconductor.org/

Comment: I can try there, though this seemed to be more of a general R issue, since this is happening in the standard package check script.

Comment: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/113650/

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. In my case `devtools::check()` was identifying the error as being in a different function than where it actually was, presumably because the automated `dev.off()` call was happening only when the second function's examples were checked. I could not solve it by simply commenting things out because the offending graphics code was not in examples but in the function itself. If I commented out the `graphics.off()` and/or `dev.off()` in my function there was a potential error if more than 62 devices were opened. So what I did was to add the following line of code: `if(length(dev.list()) > 60) graphics.off()`. That did the trick.